# Listing blog entries by year,month

Tags: python, django, date

I want to do something like this:

```
Entries.objects.values('date.year','date.month')
```

but this line is not valid. How can I list blog entries by year,month and display them in template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you set

```
entry_list = Entry.objects.order_by('pub_date')
```

in your view, you can display the months and years in the template using the [ifchanged](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) template tag.

```
{% for entry in entry_list %}
{% ifchanged %}<h3>{{entry.pub_date|date:"Y"}}</h3>{% endifchanged %}
{% ifchanged %}<h4>{{entry.pub_date|date:"F"}}</h4>{% endifchanged %}
<p>{{entry.title}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

---

Another useful Django queryset method for blog archives is [dates](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#dates-field-kind-order-asc).

For example

```
entry_months = Entry.objects.dates('pub_date','month','DESC')
```

returns a `DateQuerySet` of `datetime.datetime` objects for each month that has Blog Entries. You can use this queryset in the template to create links to monthly archive pages.

Answer (score 4):

You can try with the built-in regroup tag.

In your view:

```
archives = Entries.objects.all()
```

In your template:

```
{% regroup archives by date.month as entries_by_month %}
{% for entries in entries_by_month %}
    <h1>{{ entries.list.0.date|date:"F Y" }}</h1>
    <ul>
    {% for entry in entries.list %}
        <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code snipped from my blog where I list all of the blog entries within a certain year:

```
Entries.objects.filter(draft=drafts).filter(posted_date__year=year).order_by(order_by)
```

In the above:

- `drafts` is a boolean which specifies whether to show completed items or not.
- `year` is the selected year
- `order_by` is some ordering column name.

You should be able to easily modify this example to also include the month.
The above shows that you can combine multiple filters in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's try to do heavy lifting in data structure, instead of templates.

Let's create a utility.

```
import itertools

def group_by_values(posts, key):
    groups = {}
    for k, g in itertools.groupby(posts, key):
        if groups.get(k) is not None:
           groups[k].extend(list(g))
        else:
            groups[k] = list(g)
    return groups
```

Let's use the utility here.

```
entries = Entry.objects.all().order_by('date')
yearly_entries = group_by_values(entries, key=lambda x: x.date.year)
monthly_yearly_entries = {}
for k, v in yearly_entries.items():
    monthly_yearly_entries[k] = group_by_values(v, key=lambda x: x.date.month)
return monthly_yearly_entries
```

The result is nice dictionary with years and months as keys like this:

```
monthly_yearly_entries = {2013: {9: [Entry1, Entry2], 10: [Entry4, Entry5]}}
```

which you can show nicely in templates